# Is it possible to run Nuget update-package in parallel

Tags: performance, visual-studio-2015, nuget

I have a large solution with about 30 subprojects. Each subproject depends on a nuget package which gets updated regularly. So I end up typing for example

`Update-Package AcmeWunderLib`

every few days. The problem is this process takes about 10 minutes to run with the result being a very small change in each *package.config* and *$name$.csproj* file. Is it possible to do this operation in parallel for some performance improvement or will any attempt cause Nuget to corrupt itself?

Comment: https://github.com/NuGet/Home/issues/1909#issuecomment-282645449

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the real solution.

**DONT RUN UPDATE-PACKAGE FROM WITHIN VISUAL STUDIO**

- Close visual studio
- Open up **powershell** from the desktop or start menu
- Make sure **nuget** is on your path
- Run the following command substituting *devdept.eyeshot* for your package and *WeinCAd.Net.sln* for your solution file.

`nuget update -Verbosity detailed -Id devdept.eyeshot .\WeinCad.Net.sln`

The whole process lasted **less than 10 seconds**.

## EDIT

I have been warned that this does not do all the same things that running nuget update from within Visual Studio does. All the above does is change the base path for the DLLs. It can't add and remove references. However this is enough for my use case.

Comment: I can't mark it as the answer yet. There is a timeout when you answer your own question. But you can upvote it :)

Comment: Glad to know that you have resolved this issue. Please mark your answer which is benefit to other communities who has the same problem when you free.

Answer (score 2):

The package update time is consist of downloading package and uninstalling/installing package. The downloading action will execute only once when first time download it, so the uninstalling/installing action will occupy almost all update time.

According to your log, NuGet takes under a second to gather dependency info, but take too long time to uninstall/install package. It`s only takes 2-5 second to update a package for one project in my test. So please check your machine performance at first when you  encounter this issue.

For this issue, I would like provide you some troubleshootings：

1. Update your NuGet, NuGet team have more improvements in the pipe for 3.5rc and 3.4.5.
2. Clean the old version packages in your package feed and [NuGet cache](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/consume-packages/managing-the-nuget-cache).
3. Disable other NuGet repositories except nuget.org, perhaps one of them is timing out.
4. Test this issue on other workstations or build servers, and you can create some projects in a new solution to verify this issue.

Hope that can help you.

Comment: In my book, 2 to 5 seconds is still pretty long for what should be a simple write to disk...